# Allowing port 22 on localhost VPN only

Tags: security, ssh, vpn, iptables

I rent a remote server, and run an OpenVPN service on this server. I am trying to secure my firewall (iptables) so the only person who can access SSH is somebody connected to the VPN (localhost). However whenever I do the DROP command, I can no longer access SSH until I reboot the server because the firewall settings haven't saved before I get kicked off SSH.

Below is the code I am trying to use to accomplish this.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to the OpenVPN service gives the connecting computer a new IP address, which it can use to communicate with the server. Depending on your configuration, this new IP address might be bridged to the server real interface, or created in a new virtual "tunnel" device, which is usually called tun0. In any case, communicating with the server using the VPN will not go through the localhost interface. Check a tun0 interface exists in the host machine, and if so, try using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i tun0 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I tested it on both port 80, as well as port 22. Neither worked correctly. It just permanently stops working when I try to do that.

Comment: Maybe `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i tun+ --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` will work better

Comment: Still doing the same thing as I said before.